# Rails 3 não mostra página de debug ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debug

Meu projeto rails não mostra mais a página de debug depois que mudei o projeto de máquina.

Como eu faço para fazer tal página aparecer novamente?

Comment: Development ou production?

Comment: quando mando imprimir na tela o ENV ele retorna development.